# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

Hi iam using creative tim dark react template. im getting the following error
[Error in the image. See the image for more details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3yCh.png)

Comment: Please add some information about what you are facing. Your code, things you've tried to do, things you've done that made you end up with this error. Worth mentioning that this can be resulted from a version mismatch or dependencies being installed wring.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`process.version` return a json object you need to get the specific value that you will get from the result